# Configure Android NDK Experimental Gradle plugin to use standalone toolchain?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Is there a way to configure a android ndk gradle build using the "'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental" plugin to pick a certain standalone toolchain (created by make-standalone-toolchain.sh ) instead of the default compiler ?

Comment: Why? What kind of problem do you face? Yes it is possible to run your build command and disable the built-in native build gradle tasks.

Comment: For some of the source code files clang segfaults. It looks like that I am hitting an issue similar to this one: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159539 . The compiles fine on iOS.

Comment: Does this cause Android Studio crash or freeze? If it is "only" a build problem, maybe it would be easier to use `ndk-build NDK_TOOLCHAIN=4.8` instead of dealing with a standalone toolchain.

Comment: The gcc toolchain doesn't compile the source code, I am using boost 1.56 and other C++ 11 libraries.  Configured the ndk model with  toolchain = "clang"
        toolchainVersion = "3.6"

Comment: I think the current plugin version doesn't support the standalone tools looking at the source of the NDKHandler class here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/NdkHandler.java. It only constructs paths via the ANDROID_NDK_HOME variable. It doesn't read the ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN variable to find the paths to the compilers.

Comment: Looks like the version of master is older. It looks the studio-1.5 has version 0.4.0. May be via this class ( https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-1.5/build-system/gradle-experimental/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/ndk/internal/ToolchainConfiguration.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F  ) it can be configured. But not yet sure how to.

Comment: if you don't use Android Studio to navigate the native code, simply define `model {
    android.sources {
        main.jni.source {
            srcDirs = [] }}}` and add a new `task` **`buildNative`** `(type: Exec)` with `tasks.all {
    task ->
        if (task.name.startsWith('link')) {
            task.enabled = false
        }
        if (task.name.startsWith('compileArm')) {
            task.enabled = false
        }
        if (task.name.startsWith('bundle')) {
            task.dependsOn buildNative
        }
}`

Comment: re: ANDROID_NDK_HOME variable. You can use **local.properties** file instead, but this will not help *AS* to accept a standalone toolchain as a replacement of **ndk.dir** because it will be looking for the predefined directory structure of NDK, which is not similar to standalone toolchains.

Comment: @alex-cohn I didn't try your approach, because I found a quick hack before I read your comment. I ran `export ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/<pickname>/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
mkdir -p $ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN
$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh <params here> --install-dir=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN ` and set in the gradle script `toolchainVersion='<pickname>'`

Comment: Cool! I'm glad your problem is so easily resolved